# sorting two values at the same time in Spark sortBy

Tags: python, apache-spark

I want to sort the first and third values of my data, with the first in ascending order and thrid in descending order. I know I should use numPartitions but I cannot figure out how to write it.
I tried:

```
.sortBy(lambda x: (x[0][0], x[1][0]), ascending = (True, False), numPartitions = 1)
```

But the results turned out that the x[1][0] was still sorted in ascending order.
How should I change the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[reference pyspark 2.4.4 documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import asc, desc
from pyspark.sql.types import (IntegerType, StructType, StructField, StringType)

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

column_schema = StructType([StructField("c1", IntegerType()), StructField("c2", StringType())])
df = spark.createDataFrame([[10, "a1"], [11, "a2"], [13, "a3"], [13, "a3"]], schema=column_schema)
df.show()

sorted_df1 = df.sort(asc("c1"), desc("c2"))
sorted_df1.show()

sorted_df2 = df.orderBy(["c1", "c2"], ascending=[0, 1])
sorted_df2.show()
```

**output**

```
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
| 10| a1|
| 11| a2|
| 13| a3|
| 13| a3|
+---+---+

+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
| 10| a1|
| 11| a2|
| 13| a3|
| 13| a3|
+---+---+

+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
| 13| a3|
| 13| a3|
| 11| a2|
| 10| a1|
+---+---+
```

Comment: I figured out that```.sortBy(lambda x: (x[0][0], -x[1][0]), numPartitions = 1)```should work but yours is also fine.